# system process using 100% GPU

Tags: windows-10, gpu

I have just acquired a new laptop, ASUS ROG Strix GL503VD and i have some problems and i hope you can help me.

So i have installed the latest version of windows 10 pro (1709) and i am having major spikes even when i'm not in games, just browsing around.
I noticed that these spikes come from GPU usage which goes to 100% very briefly as you can see in the image.

[image]

Also at times i have black screen which looks like the driver is reloading, yet i am up to date with all the drivers (I'm using GTX 1050 4gb and installed the latest drivers with nVidia Xperience). I noticed that the process taking up 100% of GPU is System. Could this be a windows problem ? If so, would a downgrade help ?

My specs are :
Video : NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050 4GB,
CPU : Intel Core I7-7700HQ,
RAM : 8GB

Comment: What happens when you try and use an external monitor?

Comment: That GPU graph is for the integrated GPU that the Intel processor provides. Since the integrated GPU is weaker than the dedicated Nvidia GPU, any activity on the integrated GPU will display a higher percentage on the graph than what would appear on the dedicated GPU graph.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sonickyle27 said, the graph you're looking at is for the integrated Intel graphics. The integrated graphics chip isn't particularly powerful, so it will hit 90+% usage fairly easily. The graph for the dedicated GPU, on the other hand, looks like it is constantly at zero. The GPU is far more powerful than the integrated chip, so it won't hit 100% usage as readily as the integrated graphics will.

[image: Cropped screenshot of sidebar graphs]

If you look at that section of the screenshot you posted, you'll see you're looking at the Intel graphics instead of the Nvidia GPU. Switch over to "GPU 2" to see the usage of the actual GPU